# Quero ocultar o small

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

Tenho um select que possui um  com um texto descritivo.
Preciso que ele fique oculto, quando clicar no select e abrir a lista de opções, mas que volte a ser visível quando clicar no select, ou em uma das opções da lista.

```
<div id="select-default" class="select-box">
  <div class="options-container">
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="label41" name="opcoes" />
      <label class="label-opcao" for="label41">label 41</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="label42" name="opcoes" />
      <label class="label-opcao" for="label42">label 42</label>
    </div>
    <div id="selected-default" class="selected selected-erro" onclick="ocultar ('conteudo')">
      selecione...
    </div>
    <p id="label-select-erro" class="label-select">label</p>
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo">
    <div class="div-mensagem-select">
      <small class="mensagem-select text-roxo float-left">
        <p>Mensagem de erro</p>
      </small>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Usei esta função....

```
<script>
function ocultar(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(display == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
```

Do jeito que está ele fica novamente visível quando dá o segundo click no select, mas não fica visível quando clica em uma das opções....

Answer (score 0):

Faça a verificação assim:

```
if (display !== 'block')
```

Precisa ser feito assim pois o valor de `style.display` por padrão vem em branco – e não é afetado por definições feitas via CSS.